# Make submit work by pressing enter on PHP and Javascript login page

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, onclick

I'm pretty new to Javascript and I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I can't figure it out.

I'm using a slightly modified version of the code from [this page](http://marakana.com/blog/examples/php-implementing-secure-login-with-php-javascript-and-sessions-without-ssl.html) and I want to make the form work by entering the information and pressing enter rather than having to click the button.

FYI I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239082/javascript-login-form-doesnt-submit-when-user-hits-enter) and can't work out my own answer from there. I tried changing the type to "submit" from "button" but then the login didn't work. I've also tried changing "onlick" to "onsubmit" and had the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a type of "submit" but change the onclick to `onclick="loginFunction(); return false;"`

The `return false` stops the submit button from actually doing the submit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit a form  on click of button instead of enter then no need to use input type="submit" instead of this you can use input type='button' and set a onclick function in this like input type="button" onclick="my_func()" and in the definiton of this function my_func you can use document.formname.submit() for submitting the form.
  hope it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Set the "tab index" property of your html elements with your button having the highest index (or one up after the last html element)