# Detect enter key pressed using javascript

Tags: javascript, enter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript capture key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756786/javascript-capture-key)

I'm working on reply function using mysql and php.

My MySQL db:

```
reply:
  rid - id;
  topicid - under which topic;
  uid - id of the guy who replies;
  content - what did the guy said.
```

Here's my html code:

```
<form id="replyform">
  <textarea name="rplcont" placeholder="Press enter to submit your reply."><textarea>
</form>
```

My question is: How do I know if enter button is pressed?

Many thanks.

/*----------------------------------------------*/

here's my codes that work:

html:

```
<textarea id="reply" name="reply" onKeyPress="enterpressalert(event, this)"></textarea>
```

js:

```
function enterpressalert(e, textarea){
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
 alert('enter press');
}
}
```

and it works.

Thanks for everyone who concerns this topic!

Comment: Dups everywhere! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=enter+key+javascript

Comment: You will find related info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239082/javascript-login-form-doesnt-submit-when-user-hits-enter

Comment: @VishalSuthar: Thanks, u are really generous. I'm reading it right now..

Comment: if(code == 13) { alert('You pressed Enter, the unlucky number!') }

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    alert('enter press');
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply! I edit your code a little bit.. 
function doit(e, textarea){
    ... // your code
}

Comment: `e.keyCode` is now deprecated. Mozilla recommends using `if (e.code === "Enter")`, even though Microsoft browsers lack support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code