# How to call keypress event of button by pressing ENTER in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application I have one button and one text box. Now I have call one function of jQuery on click and keypress event of button.

now i want that the same function is call when the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press on text box.

is there any way to call that jQuery function?

I have not form this both elements are work without form

Comment: Perhaps take a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery

Comment: NO, it's not in form tag

Comment: @699065 read my question properly form is not used there

Comment: @user3363563 That isn't who left the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#search_btn').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {

        alert("Enter pressed");
       //Call your function here, or trigger the button click.
    }
});
```

**`DEMO:`**  http://jsfiddle.net/skhan/brdaj/

Answer (score 1):

you can use keypress() with **jquery**, like this :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        console.log("2");
    }
});
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/bfR6N/)

If you dont want to make with jquery,(**form onsubmit or javascript**) check this source :

[Detect enter key pressed using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251676/detect-enter-key-pressed-using-javascript)

and this one;

[Enter key press event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){
   if(e.which == 13 && $('#yourText').is(':focus')){
     console.log("do your thing");
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L2M3Y/1/